# Gaierror while importing pretrained vgg model on kaggle

Tags: python, keras, kaggle

```
initial_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', pooling = max)
```

I am trying to import a pre-trained VGG model in keras on kaggle. I run through an gaierror which was unfamiliar.

> Downloading data from
>   https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg19_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last) /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
>   http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1317
>   h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
>   -> 1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1319
>   except OSError as err: # timeout error
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in request(self, method, url,
>   body, headers, encode_chunked)    1238         """Send a complete
>   request to the server."""
>   -> 1239         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)    1240
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method,
>   url, body, headers, encode_chunked)    1284             body =
>   _encode(body, 'body')
>   -> 1285         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)    1286
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in endheaders(self,
>   message_body, encode_chunked)    1233             raise
>   CannotSendHeader()
>   -> 1234         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)    1235
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_output(self,
>   message_body, encode_chunked)    1025         del self._buffer[:]
>   -> 1026         self.send(msg)    1027
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in send(self, data)
>       963             if self.auto_open:
>   --> 964                 self.connect()
>       965             else:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in connect(self)    1391 
>   -> 1392             super().connect()    1393
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in connect(self)
>       935         self.sock = self._create_connection(
>   --> 936             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
>       937         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socket.py in create_connection(address,
>   timeout, source_address)
>       703     err = None
>   --> 704     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
>       705         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family,
>   type, proto, flags)
>       744     addrlist = []
>   --> 745     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
>       746         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
>
> gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last) /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py
>   in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, file_hash, cache_subdir,
>   hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)
>       221             try:
>   --> 222                 urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
>       223             except HTTPError as e:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlretrieve(url,
>   filename, reporthook, data)
>       247 
>   --> 248     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
>       249         headers = fp.info()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data,
>   timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
>       222         opener = _opener
>   --> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>       224
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl,
>   data, timeout)
>       525 
>   --> 526         response = self._open(req, data)
>       527
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _open(self, req, data)
>       543         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
>   --> 544                                   '_open', req)
>       545         if result:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain,
>   kind, meth_name, *args)
>       503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
>   --> 504             result = func(*args)
>       505             if result is not None:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in https_open(self, req)
>   1360             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
>   -> 1361                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)    1362
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
>   http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1319             except OSError
>   as err: # timeout error
>   -> 1320                 raise URLError(err)    1321             r = h.getresponse()
>
> URLError:
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 initial_model = VGG19(include_top=False, input_shape=(128,128,3), weights='imagenet')
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/applications/**init**.py
>   in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>        26             kwargs['models'] = models
>        27             kwargs['utils'] = utils
>   ---> 28         return base_fun(*args, **kwargs)
>        29 
>        30     return wrapper
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/applications/vgg19.py in
>   VGG19(*args, **kwargs)
>         9 @keras_modules_injection
>        10 def VGG19(*args, **kwargs):
>   ---> 11     return vgg19.VGG19(*args, **kwargs)
>        12 
>        13
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_applications/vgg19.py in
>   VGG19(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling,
>   classes, **kwargs)
>       219                 WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP,
>       220                 cache_subdir='models',
>   --> 221                 file_hash='253f8cb515780f3b799900260a226db6')
>       222         model.load_weights(weights_path)
>       223         if backend.backend() == 'theano':
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py in
>   get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, file_hash, cache_subdir,
>   hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)
>       224                 raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.code, e.msg))
>       225             except URLError as e:
>   --> 226                 raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
>       227         except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt):
>       228             if os.path.exists(fpath):
>
> Exception: URL fetch failure on
>   https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg19_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5:
>   None -- [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Hi Mav, it seems like your error is at the end of the stacktrace: it fails to fetch the data from the following URL: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg19_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5 Do you have a firewall? Or maybe something else that can block you from accessing that URL?

Comment: @thom I have a bitdefender anti-virus which is quite strict with its firewall.

Comment: @Thom Error still occurred, even though protection and firewall were down.

Comment: Is the Internet connection working on that machine? Please first try downloading the weights from a browser first.

https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg19_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might not have enabled internet access in your kernel. You can do that in the panel on the right hand side. Once you add an internet connection you'll be able to download the files.

We also actually already have [the VGG-19 weights uploaded to Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/keras/vgg19/home). If you like, you can add this existing dataset to your kernel rather than downloading it, which will probably be a little bit faster for you.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to verify the phone number, to enable the internet option. Then just enable it and re-run the notebook. Hopefully, it will work.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30668421)

Answer (score -1):

On the right hand side you will have option called "Internet", Check if it is set to 'On". If not, enable it and then try. It should work